# shell non integer argument in expr error

Tags: bash, expr

I wrote the following code in shell script:

```
num=$1
sum=0; rn=0
less=0; fact=0
while [ $num -gt 0 ]
do
rn=`expr $num % 10`
num=`expr $num / 10`
while [ $rn -gt 1 ]
do
less=`expr %rn - 1`
fact=`expr $rn \* less`
rn=`expr $rn - 1`
done
sum=`expr $sum + $fact`
done
echo $sum
```

but the terminal  shows the following error without any line number : 
[Terminal Error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plJlB.png)

Please tell me where did i mess up??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate problem is

```
less=`expr %rn - 1`
```

Change that to

```
less=`expr $rn - 1`
```

and you should sail home. But you can also debug your scripts using the `-x` option of bash which would give you a line by line analysis.

The use of `expr` is discouraged as you could easily replace that with `((expression))` construct (or `calc` if you need floating point operations). Then,

```
fact=`expr $rn \* $less`
```

will become a much easier

```
((fact=rn*less))
```

The advantage is that you should not bother escaping characters that have special meanings in `shell` like `*`

Comment: We also sometimes use variable name=$((expression)) .Does it work the same way as ((Entire thing))?? And why and where do we need to add spaces before variable for operations??

Comment: @RichiDubey For the first part of your question, the answer is yes.. The `(())` construct automatically figure out the variables for you.. For assignments in bash, it is mandatory that there are no spaces before and after the `=` sign. I can't think of any other examples where the use of spaces are restricted.